# Ask user for function name and then print .__doc__, isn't working

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script in Python, that when executed, asks the user for a function name and prints the function `.__doc__`
For example:

```
>>> print abs.__doc__
abs(number) -> number

Return the absolute value of the argument.
```

The problem is, it doesn't work with raw_input. The following is my code and what happens when it gets executed.
Code:

```
f = raw_input("Your function: ")
print f.__doc__
```

Execution:

```
Your function: abs
str(object='') -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `f` is a string object, not a function object.

Comment: You could use `__builtins__.__dict__[f].__doc__`. However that only works for builtin functions :)

Comment: What did you expect from `'abs'.__doc__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you ask to print the `__doc__` of `f` and `f` is in this case something like `'abs'`. So you call `'abs'.__doc__` which is the `__doc__` of a string.

Now you can however query for a builtin function with:

```
func = getattr(__builtins__,f)
print func.__doc__
```

this will however only work for **builtin functions**. You can also look for `globals()` or `locals()` which are dictionaries storing the global and local variables respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your problem is trying to use the string reply from `raw_input()` as a function object.  You could get the function object by calling `getattr()`, but you need to known which module it is in.  OK, so you could go through the global namespace looking for it, but there is a much simpler solution, just use `pydoc`:

```
f = raw_input("Your function: ")

help(f)
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, abs is a method that you're querying the `__doc__` on.  The `raw_input` is converting the input value to a string, so what you're really executing the `__doc__` on is a string.

You get the same results if you do this:

```
z = ''
print z.__doc__
```